# implement drag and double tap on the same view android

Tags: android, drag

I want to implement both drag and double tap event on the `EditText` but I'm able to implement only either of the two. The idea behind this is as the user double taps the edit text the edit text becomes enable, and with drag he can drag it whereever he wants.

```
text.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)==true && gestureDetector!=null){
                    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
                else
                {drag(event, v);
                return true; }
            }

            private void drag(MotionEvent event, View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v
                        .getLayoutParams();

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    params.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                    params.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX()
                            - (v.getWidth() / 2);
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    params.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                    params.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX()
                            - (v.getWidth() / 2);
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                    break;
                }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got the solution

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int X = (int) event.getRawX();
            int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
            layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v
                        .getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;

                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (upCounter != 0) {
                    timeBetweenTwoClick = startTime - endTime;
                }

                mSingleStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                mSingleEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
                currentClickTime = endTime - startTime;
                consecutiveTwoClickTime = currentClickTime
                        + previousClickTime;

                // textview single tap detection
                if (mSingleEnd - mSingleStart <= mSingleTimeDiffrence) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tap", 1500).show();

                    if (mSingleCount == false) {
                        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                        gd.setCornerRadius(5);
                        gd.setStroke(3, 0xFF000000);
                        text.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                        verticalSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        verticalSeekBar
                                .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(
                                            SeekBar seekBar) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method
                                        // stub

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(
                                            SeekBar seekBar) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method
                                        // stub

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onProgressChanged(
                                            SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                            boolean fromUser) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method
                                        // stub
                                        text.setTextSize(progress + 20);
                                        text2.setTextSize(progress + 20);
                                    }
                                });

                        mSingleCount = true;
                    } else {
                        text.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                        mSingleCount = false;
                        verticalSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                }

                if (upCounter == 0) {
                    ++upCounter;
                    previousClickTime = currentClickTime;
                }

                else {
                    previousClickTime = currentClickTime;
                    if ((consecutiveTwoClickTime + timeBetweenTwoClick) <= doubleClickTimeDiffrence) {

                        if (layoutParams != null)
                            text2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                        text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        text2.requestFocus();

                        if (text2.getText().toString()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("enter by double tap")) {
                            text2.setText("");

                        }
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(text2,
                                InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                        text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "double tap",
                                1500).show();
                    }

                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                if (layoutParams.leftMargin < 0) {
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;
                } else if (layoutParams.leftMargin > mainimage.getWidth()) {
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = mainimage.getWidth() - 20;
                }
                if (layoutParams.topMargin < 0) {
                    layoutParams.topMargin = 20;
                } else if (layoutParams.topMargin > mainimage.getHeight() - 100) {
                    text.setText(text2.getText().toString());
                    layoutParams.topMargin = mainimage.getHeight() - 90
                            - text.getHeight();
                    // layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;
                }

                text.setX(layoutParams.leftMargin);
                text.setY(layoutParams.topMargin);

                v.setLayoutParams(text.getLayoutParams());

                Log.i("mainimage.getHeight() ",
                        (mainimage.getHeight() - 60) + " "
                                + layoutParams.topMargin + " "
                                + text.getHeight());

                // if (text.getLeft() >= 0 && text.getTop() >= 0
                // && text.getRight() < width
                // && text.getBottom() < mainimage.getHeight()) {
                //
                // text.setX(layoutParams.leftMargin);
                // text.setY(layoutParams.topMargin);
                // } else if (text.getTop() < 0) {
                //
                // text.setX(layoutParams.leftMargin);
                // text.setY(10);
                // } else if (text.getBottom() > mainimage.getHeight()) {
                // text.setX(layoutParams.leftMargin);
                // text.setY(mainimage.getHeight() - 50);
                // } else if (text.getLeft() < 0) {
                // text.setX(10);
                // text.setY(layoutParams.topMargin);
                // } else if (text.getRight() > mainimage.getWidth()) {
                //
                // text.setX(mainimage.getWidth() - 10);
                // text.setY(layoutParams.topMargin);
                // }
                // else {
                // text.setX(20);
                // text.setY(20);
                // }

                // layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                // layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;

                // if (text.getWidth() < (width - 50)) {
                //
                // }

                // text.setWidth(width - text.getLeft());

                // Log.i("From Current position: ",
                // "Left Margin: " + X + " " + _xDelta
                // + "Left Margin: " + Y + " " + _yDelta
                // + "layoutParams.leftMargin: "
                // + layoutParams.leftMargin
                // + " layoutParams.topMargin: "
                // + layoutParams.topMargin
                // + " layoutParams.height - width: "
                // + layoutParams.height + " " + width
                // + " " + (width - text.getWidth()) + " "
                // + text.getWidth());
                break;
```